# React route does not getting displayed without click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I want to use react router for the navigation of my app. It is an electron desktop app, so my debugging is limited. When the login goes (which runs without routers) a component with a router gets displayed, but when this component gets displayed, it does not display the exact route "/". Only if I click the "Link" component it gets displayed. I am using the `BrowserRouter` Component. Does anyone have an idea?

That's the parent components render method:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div style={styles.text}>
                <AppBar title={this.state.title}/>
                <Grid container className='mainGrid'>
                    <Grid item>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <BottomNav/>
                <Sidenav/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Thats the BottomNav render method:

```
render() {
    const {value} = this.state;
    return (
        <BottomNavigation className='BottomNav' showLabels value={value}
                          onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <BottomNavigationAction component={Link} to="/" label="Feed" icon={<BookIcon/>}/>
            <BottomNavigationAction component={Link} to="/calendar" label="Calendar" icon={<CalendarIcon/>}/>
            <BottomNavigationAction component={Link} to="/mail" label="Mail" icon={<MailIcon/>}/>
            <BottomNavigationAction component={Link} to="/tickets" label="Tickets" icon={<AssignmentIcon/>}/>
        </BottomNavigation>)
}
```

And that's the Feed components render method:

```
render(){
    return(
        <h1>Hallo Welt (Feed)</h1>
    )
}
```

If you need more information, please write a comment.

Comment: Which router component are you using e.g. BrowserRouter, HashRouter, ...?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I am using BrowserRouter. Ill edit it

Comment: When I put a <Redirect /> right in front of that, it works, but thats not a good solution I think

Comment: are you sure the login redirects to the "/" route? 
because your route is exact, so only the exact "/" will match

Comment: No, the login does not redirect to the "/" route. It only renders the parent component from the router if it succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the surrounding [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch) component which renders the first Route that matches automatically.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Feed} />
</Switch>
```

**Edit**

It seems that the initial route of your location is an empty string and not `/`. I never encountered this behavior, so it might be server related?

I can think of these two solutions:

**Add  a redirect**

Add a `<Redirect from="" to="/" />` in your App.jsx. This will force a forward slash in your path.

**Disable Route strict mode**

React router has added an `exact` prop for issues with a trailing slash. Although, I'm not 100% sure this will work in your example.

`<Route exact path="/" component={Feed} exact={false} />`

Comment: Okay, if I remove the `exact` keyword, it renders the route, but for all routes. :D

Comment: Could you add a working example with JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/?

Comment: Its a bit complex, there are 12 files with components and Material-UI

Comment: Hmm, it is possible the initial path is an empty string. What happens if you add a second route with an empty string as the path?

Comment: Yea its absolutely possible. But how do I Route that

Comment: Okay, I added it, and at this point, every route is getting this component. Even if i define a second one with a completely different path. Could you edit your answer, maybe I dont understand.

Comment: So, now I just have the other 3 routes on top, so that the path="" route is last and it works. But is that the best solution?

Comment: I've added more solutions. IMO adding a second route is not the best solution.

Comment: I dont think its server related, its only absolutely bad coded, or complex, I think. Ill try

Comment: So, I have build a workaround. I just used react routers for the login component too and than it worked, thanks for your effort